# Driver for the Killer E2201 and XP

Tags: lan

I have a new Gigabyte GA-970 Gaming MoBo which has, of all things, a Killer e2201 Lan chip.  Unfortunately there are instances when I need to connect WinXP to the Internet and as near as I can tell there is no XP driver for the Killer e2201.  Is there some way to get around this impasse?

Comment: Yes. Install a newer supported operating system. XP is unsupported, out of date, and full of security holes. It should not be allowed on the internet ;)

Comment: I'm submitting an answer which contains the same basic info that was provided by @DavidPostill's rude comment, though my answer tries to do so in a manner which is much less hostile to end users.  Operating systems like Windows 95 OSR2 and OS/2 3.0 were designed to be able to connect to the Internet, which is de-centralized and so there are no regulations about what software to connect.  XP doesn't have significantly more/worse security holes than the day it was released, so by the same logic would indicate that the current Windows version probably should not be released on the Internet either

Comment: @TOOGAM I object to the "rude comment". Did you not see the `;)` at the end of my comment? In addition, if there are security issues with current operating systems they can be mostly patched with updates.

Comment: All Gigabyte shows for that board are Realtek drivers, for any OS?

Comment: 2100 drivers for XP here...https://www.visiontek.com/download-drivers.html

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty, if the only component not working in a nearly 15 year old OS on your new hardware is the network card, I'd say you've done okay.

Realistically though there likely won't be a way to make it work if there is no driver available for XP, and in your situation I'd consider one of the following actions:

- If you need to use Windows XP as your main OS for a specific reason, consider purchasing a PCIe or USB network adapter that does have XP drivers.
- Use a more modern Windows or Unix OS and consider running Windows XP in a virtual machine if you simply require XP for a specific purpose.

Comment: I completely agree with the VM option.

Answer (score -1):

If the hardware manufacturer has chosen not to support an older operating system, there is typically no available option except to create a driver yourself.  There is no typical way to do that, because this is not typically done.  People interested in using newer hardware typically accept that it is time to upgrade to a new operating system.

If you're resistant to using newer Microsoft operating systems due to some sort of changes, you may with to consider making one more change, away from Microsoft.  For instance, Linux Mint is well known for offering desktop environments that are designed to retain the basic "look at feel" of desktops that people are familiar and comfortable with.  The move/switch may be more challenging than upgrading to Windows 10, but then hopefully you won't be feeling quite as coerced to adopt numerous unwanted changes on a regular basis (compared to if you remained committed to using Microsoft operating systems, which have regularly had substantial new differences to the user interface with each major version).